# Failed to derive template parameters for "T"

Tags: c++

i don't know how to use the function declared before,because it's said *Failed to derive template parameters for `T`*; That is the function template is not matched. But how i use the function? Here is the code.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

template <typename T> void getOriginLbp(InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst){
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    _dst.create(src.rows - 2, src.cols - 2, CV_8UC1);
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();
    dst.setTo(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < src.rows - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < src.cols - 1; j++)
        {
            T center = src.at<T>(i, j);
            unsigned char lbpcode = 0;          
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i - 1, j - 1)>center) << 7;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i - 1, j)>center) << 6;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i - 1, j + 1) > center) << 5;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i, j + 1) > center) << 4;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i + 1, j + 1) > center) << 3;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i + 1, j) > center) << 2;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i + 1, j - 1) > center) << 1;
            lbpcode |= (src.at<T>(i, j - 1) > center);
            dst.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1) = lbpcode;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat srcImg = imread("pep.jpg");
    cvtColor(srcImg, srcImg, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat LbpImg;
    getOriginLbp(srcImg, LbpImg);
    imshow("originLbp", LbpImg);
    return 0;
}
```

SO how to use the `getOriginLbp` function? Maybe I'm using the wrong parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a type when calling a [templated function](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templated_functions.html), like this:

```
getOriginLbp<type>(srcImg, LbpImg);
```

<strike>I'm not sure what `type` should be in your case. Maybe `Mat`.</strike>

---

## Edit

Okay, I'm looking at the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) and it looks like `type` should be the data type of whatever's being stored in your matrix, `int`, `double`, etc. It looks like you're reading image data. Just try both `int` and `double` and see if one works. If not, `cout` an element in the matrix to try to infer its type.